# Loop through an array and build navigation menu with it

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to build a navigation 'system', where the categories and subcategories are stored in an array.

This is the array:

```
$navigation = array(

'users' =>  array(

    'view'      =>  1,
    'edit'      =>  1,
    'delete'    =>  1,
    'list'      =>  1

),

'profiles'      =>  array(

    'view'      =>  4,
    'edit'      =>  4,

),

'projects'      =>  array(

    'new'       =>  3,
    'edit'      =>  3,
    'delete'    =>  1,
    'list'      =>  2,
    'mylist'    =>  3

)
```

);

With this array I would like to loop through each item and if the users' rank is equal or lower than the values (1, 2, 3) show them the appropriate links.
But I don't realy know how to start on it.

Hope this is clear enough!

Comment: _`if the users' rank is equal or lower than the values (1, 2, 3)`_ the users rank is equal to what value ?

Comment: The value of the subcategories (like new = 1, or edit = 3, etc). A users' rank corresponds to the permissions he'll get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($navigation as $category) {

    // need to track if main categories have been output already
    $category_already_output = false;

    foreach ($category as $subcategory => $permission) {

        if ($current_user_permission_level <= $permission) {

            if ( ! $category_already_output ) {
                // output your html for this main category nav here
                $category_already_output = true;
            }

            // output your html for this subcategory here

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The above assumes you don't want to show a main category if a user does not have permissions for any of its subcategories. If you want to show every main category all the time, then you can simplify this to:

```
foreach ($navigation as $category) {

    // output main category html here

    foreach ($category as $subcategory => $permission) {

        if ($current_user_permission_level <= $permission) {

            // output your html for this subcategory here

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give some explanation about the `$category_already_output = false` and the `$category_already_output = true` ? Thanks!

Comment: That technique is completely optional. You could instead output the main navigation category just before starting the 2nd foreach loop if you always want to show every category in the nav. The advantage of outputting the main nav category inside the inner foreach is that if a user does not have ANY valid permissions for say 'profiles', then you avoid showing them a profiles nav link at all.